# Java Spring MVC get .tag properties to .jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a Java configured Spring MVC application. I would like to know, how to access properties defined in `WEB-INF\tags`. 
AppConfig.java:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("/i18/usermsg");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en_US"));
    resolver.setCookieName("myLocaleCookie");
    resolver.setCookieMaxAge(4800);
    return resolver;
}
```

usermsg_en.properties: 
`user.test=This is a test`

WEB-INF\tags\test.tag:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c"   uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@attribute name="front"   required="false" description="some description" %>
<head>
    <spring:message code="user.test" var="user_test" text="default text"/>
</head>
```

In .jsp file this doesn't work:

```
<t:head front="true"/>
<body>
    ${user_test}
</body>
```

But it works if I include `<spring:message code="user.test" var="user_test" text="default text"/>` directly in .jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: 

This 
`<spring:message code="user.test" var="user_test" text="default text"/>`

should be

`<spring:message code="user.test" var="user_test" text="default text" scope="request"/>`

Then you can access variables defined in `.tag` files with `${user_test}`

Answer (score 0):

`<spring:message>` should work in `tag` as well as in `jsp` files.

I think the problem is that you have not included the spring taglib in your `tag` file. So add:

```
<%@taglib prefix="spring"   uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this surely isn't the case because I have other things defined in .tag files such as scripts which are imported correctly. Also, the taglib IS included in my .tag file :)